# Retrieve models based on generic relation

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a `GenericForeignKey` with represents a comment:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and several models linked to it

```
class Foo(PiuModel):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name=‘foos’)

class Bar(PiuModel):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name=‘bars’)
```

Is there a simple way to retrieve all the `ContentType` for models with this `GenericRelation` as a **queryset**? If not what's the simplest way?

Comment: I'm not sure what result do you want. What do you mean "retrieve all the models with a queryset"? Do you want all the model names that has comments? Or do you want all objects with each model that has comments?

Comment: I want models. I was thinking of a queryset on ContentType: ```ContentType.objects.filter('has_relation_with_comment=True')```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ct = Comment.objects.values_list('content_type, flat=True).distinct()
content_types = ContentType.objects.filter(id__in=ct)
```

Comment: This solution depends on data and not configuration. It does not work if i have no comment in my table